# Can an JS / Android App create dynamic Firebase DB for google authenticated logging user

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to create on the fly, for any google authenticated user, a firebase DB. Let us say a fitness data application. When User A logs in to the application (authenticated by user's google id), the user will have his/her own exclusive Firebase DB created dynamically to store A's fitness data. When another User B logs in he/she will have his/her own new firebase db with B's own fitness data.

Is this feasible?

Comment: Technically you could create a totally separate Firebase app  - but that seems like a bit of an overkill. Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible.  You're supposed to use security rules to determine who can read their own dedicated part of a single database, usually using their UID assigned by Firebase Authentication.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security